How to highlight a text in an array that is controlled by another array?
I want to develop a website that helps to practice English.
I have some videos and each video has some interesting English sentences that I want the website to read them out loud several times.
Say, video 1 has 3 sentences and each sentence has a start-time and end-time in the video
For example,
video 1-> "I turned on the tab" (1:02 to 1:04)
video 1-> "I signed up for piano lessons" (1:10 to 1:12)
video 1-> "Don't be so dramatic" (2:10 to 2:11)
Say, video 2 has 5 sentences and each sentence has a start-time and end-time in the video
video 2-> "sentence 1" (1:02 to 1:03)
video 2-> "sentence 2" (1:05 to 1:06)
etc
I want this
when the system loads, it will list all the sentences in a table of 2 columns for each video like this
<href>Video 1 </href>

<table>
<tr>
 <td> <href> I turned on the tab </href></td>
  <td> <href> I signed up for piano lessons </href></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <href> Don't be so dramatic </href></td>
 <td> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<href>video 2 </href>

<table>
<tr>
 <td> <href> Sentence 1 </href></td>
  <td> <href>Sentence 2 </href></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <href> Sentence 3 </href></td>
 <td> <href> Sentence 4 </href> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <href> Sentence 5 </href> </td>
 <td> </td>
</tr>

</table>

Now, when the website reads 3 times sentence 1 (I turned on the tab) of the video 1 , the "sentence 1" will highlight. Then it reads 3 times sentence 2 of video 1, the "sentence 1" will stop highlighting and the "sentence 2" will highlight. This will keep doing like that until the last sentence of the last video in the video list.
When users click on the sentence link, it will call the part of the video containing that sentence.
I did the first part, the video calls works
But I have not finished the highlight part and "clicking on the sentence link" part


var sentences = [
  ['https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4', [
      [1, 2],
      [5, 7]
    ],
    [
      ['sentence 1'],
      ['sentence 2']
    ]
  ],
  ['https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4', [
      [10, 12],
      [13, 17],
      [25, 36]
    ],
    [
      ['sentence 1'],
      ['sentence 2'],
      ['sentence 3']
    ]
  ],
  ['https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WeAreGoingOnBullrun.mp4', [
      [13, 15],
      [15, 19],
      [21, 30]
    ],
    [
      ['sentence 1'],
      ['sentence 2'],
      ['sentence 3']
    ]
  ]
];

let video_index = 0;
let time_index = 0;
let repeat = 0;

var video;
var maxTime;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (video.currentTime >= maxTime) {
      myLoop();
    }
  }, false);
});

function playVideo(myUrl, startTime, endTime) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myUrl + " start:" + startTime + " end: " + endTime + "<br>";

  // video.src = 'video/'+myUrl;
  video.src = myUrl;
  video.currentTime = startTime;
  video.play();
  maxTime = endTime;
}


function myLoop() {
  if (!sentences[video_index]) {
    video.src = null;
    return;
  }
  playVideo(sentences[video_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][0], sentences[video_index][1][time_index][1]);
  repeat++;
  if (repeat >= 3) {
    repeat = 0;
    time_index++;
    if (time_index >= sentences[video_index][1].length) {
      time_index = 0;
      video_index++;
    }
  }
}

function jumpToVideo(vid_index){
    
  let text = "Do you want to play this video?";
  if (confirm(text) == true) {
    video_index = vid_index;
    time_index = 0;
    repeat = 0;
    myLoop();
  } 
    
}
function listVideos() {
  var vid_index = 0;
  for (const sentence of sentences) {

    const [video, timers, englishSentences] = sentence
    var videoLink = "<a href='#' onclick='jumpToVideo(" + vid_index + ")' >" + video + "</a><br><br>";

    document.getElementById("allVideos").innerHTML += videoLink;
    vid_index++;
  }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',listVideos); // better than onload
<video id="myVideo" width="500" height="400" controls autoplay loop>
    
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

<br>
<a href="#" onclick="myLoop()"> Play </a>

<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="allVideos"></p>




The best way IMO would be to edit your video directly rather than trying to sync video and audio in HTML/Javascript

@mplungjan,  I have not finished the highlight part and "clicking on the sentence link" part

@mplungjan, no  you can see the demo https://vyha18.github.io/video/
try "Jemima Takes Care of the Ducklings - Episde 1: One Baby"

I would suggest working with a custom JS map function (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp). Lets say you want to highlight specific items of the video objects defined in videos, by using an external array highlighted_videos where the video ID's are defined that should be highlighted on the frontend.
By defining 2 arrays you could define a custom JS map function (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp), in this particular case isHighlightedMap which will return true/false depending on the condition if the video is in the highlight_ids array.
// Array with video objects
const videos = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Video 1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Video 2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Video 3'}
];

// Video object id's to be highlighted
const highlight_ids = [1, 3];

// Defining the highlighted video's based on the video object array
const highlighted_videos = videos.map(isHighlightedMap);

// Array map function, returns whether the video is in the highlight_ids
function isHighlightedMap(video) {
  return highlight_ids.includes[video.id];
}

Now you would be able to define in your page build if the video id is in the highlighted_videos array by using array find or search methods, if the value is found in the mapped array, you could apply the CSS selector for highlighting the video on your frontend.
Perhaps you could work without the map function: search directly on the highlight_ids, this way there is no validation whether or not the video is actually defined and might result in faulty behaviour on non-existing video ID's.
